# Excel formula calculation for Priority

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula which calculates the Priority based on certain date criteria. If the Date is less than 365 from Today then make it "Priority 2" or else "Priority 1".

This works fine but i want the priority to be calculated when the application is OPEN and once the application is closed the Priority should not change based on the date criteria in the formula.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Once the application is open, examine the result of the formula.  If the result is satisfactory and you wish to "fix" it, copy the cell and PasteSpecialValues back onto the cell.  Then save the file and close the application.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there a automated way of doing this?

Comment: @user3331363 To automate this would require an **Event macro** probably the Calculate event.